# Bounty ad not appearing correctly

Tags: bug, status-norepro, bounty, advertising

I was looking at a question and I saw this:

[image]

It looks like a bounty ad's image wasn't loading. In case you are wondering, the image URL was https://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/codegolf.stackexchange.com/bounty.png and it was failing with a HTTP 500, and I wasn't logged in when this happened.. Could someone fix this?

Comment: This happens when I view pictures on SE at school, due to imgur being blocked, but this is different (maybe).

Comment: Ads can be found [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/11408)

Comment: This keep borking, on and off again.  It's up around 80% of the time, but yeah it crashes occasionally. The only thing anybody can do is contact the bounty ad maker.

Comment: Actually, the other thing we can do: [The source code for the ad is available on github.](https://github.com/kylecronin/Stack-Exchange-Bounty-Ad) If sometimes has a webserver they're willing to use for this, they can set up the bounty ad by themselves.  It would be vulnerable to the same problem though: the server going down.

Comment: @programmer5000 hah, it's frozen at 99 bounties. (there are 362 atm)

Comment: Hmm, It must be the HTTPS force I think.